# @tinymce/tinymce-react - How do I change in code the focus?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I try to focus the TinyMCE text editor by pressing a button, with `auto_focus` it does not work, unfortunately.
My TinyMCE component use:

```html
<Editor
        apiKey='*************'
        onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
        init={{
          height: 500,
          width: "100%",
          auto_focus: isInFocus, // not working
          menubar: false,
          inline: true,
          plugins: [

          ],
          toolbar: 'bold italic underline | undo redo | alignleft aligncenter ' +
          'alignright alignjustify',
          content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
        }}
      />
```

The solutions on the internet do not talk about the package `npm @tinymce/tinymce-react`.
Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself pretty quickly:
I used the `useEffect` hook and the `editorRef.current.focus()` function:

```
export default function TinymceInlineEditor({isInFocus}) {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      isInFocus ? editorRef.current.focus() : null;
    }, [isInFocus]);

  return (
      <Editor
        apiKey='************'
        onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
        onBlur={(e) => handelBlur(editorRef)}
        init={{
          height: 500,
          width: "100%",
          menubar: false,
          inline: true,
          plugins: [

          ],
          toolbar: 'bold italic underline | undo redo | alignleft aligncenter ' +
          'alignright alignjustify',
          content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
        }}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: is there any way to hold the focus on default popup like link popup ?